# Asset not rendering

Tags: rendering

Please see the attached screen shot. Notice the floor. In the top of the picture I am looking at a quick render in the viewport pressing shift+Z, In the bottom window is the render out from a "proper render." What on earth could I have done to ma[image]ke that happen?

Comment: Have you checked the Outliner to see if the floor is set to not render? If the  eye is showing for the view but the camera isn't then maybe you can just toggle the camera back on that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm so dumb I shouldn't be allowed to use this program......let alone a really nice computer. There is a hidden wall in the way of the camera which is not set to 'not render' so it was getting in the way of the camera. In my own defence, and there probably isn't one, the camera was viewing at the exact join of the  perspective point of the cabinets and the floor. Doh!!!!!